# String to list when missing comma in string

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, string-literals

I have kinda painted myself in corner by converting vectors fom a dataframe to `str`. My vectors now look like this `[ -9.1676396 -171.8196878]`. The problem is that they somehow lost the comma in the middle, used to be like this `[ -9.1676396, -171.8196878]`. Then, whenever I would need a list conversion I could do:

```
literal_eval('[ -9.1676396, -171.8196878]')
```

However this no longer works since I've lost the comma. My question is, how can I transform a string like this in a list? I also have to account for the fact that some may differ in spacing. Here is the type of edits I could have:

```
[ -9.1676396 -171.8196878 ]
[1.2904753 103.8520359]
[   21.2160437 -157.975203 ]
```

Comment: Remove `[` and `]`, make `split` and convert results to float: `[float(x) for x in  '[ -9.1676396 -171.8196878]'.replace('[','').replace(']','').split()]`.

Comment: can you add some more info on what Type you are getting?

Comment: @MosheSlavin just do literal_eval('[ -9.1676396, -171.8196878]') and see for yourself. I am not on a computer right now, but I think it was adding the numbers, so it was not returning a list

Comment: @StanislavIvanov that worked!, if you write it as an answer, I will mark it as the solution to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have line like:

```
[ -9.1676396 -171.8196878 ]
```

It can be easily converted to list of floats by follow code:

```
[float(x) for x in '[ -9.1676396 -171.8196878]'.replace('[','').replace(']','').split()]
```

This code removes `[` and `]` symbols, splits line with space as separator and converts resulting string parts into floats.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn’t look like you have a string anymore, Just an array.

I suggest you use regex

```
 import re

 pattern =  "/[\s" #replace spaces on outside of numbers if any
 replace = "" # i.e nothing
 re.sub(pattern, replace)
```

Then do the same thing again but regex pattern would be

```
 re.sub([0-9]*\s[0-9]* , ",")
```

Comment: actually what I have is not an array, it looks like an array, but it really is just a string, as so '[ -9.1676396 -171.8196878 ]'.